# Sort elements by many properties in Scala

Tags: scala, sorting

I have list of Strings like:

```
"200-foo-02 bar"
"201-woo-21 bar foo 21 bar"
"200-foo2 02"
```

I would like to have it sorted by multiple properties (parts of string separated by commas and dashes)

What more, I want to use string ordering for strings and Int ordering for Ints

Length of input is unknown.

For example input:

```
"200-foo-02 bar"
"200-foo2 02"
"201-woo-21 bar foo 21 bar"
```

Comment: Did you tried something youself?

Comment: What order you expect for `"foo", "123"` and why?

Answer (score 1):

Sort is stable in scala, you can do it in-order you require:

```
val elems = List("200-foo-02 bar", "201-woo-21 bar foo 21 bar", "200-foo2 02")
```

### Updated: Includes split on both `-` and `<space>`.

```
elems.sortBy(_.split("[-, ]").head)

>> Result: List(200-foo-02 bar, 200-foo2 02, 201-woo-21 bar foo 21 bar)
```

Comment: yeah, but 1) I don't know lenght of list 2) I want to split also by spaces

Comment: @Wieloming 1) You don't need to know the length of the list 2) You can give all the separator characters as the argument to `split`, e.g. `split("[-, ]")` will split on dashes, commas and spaces.

Comment: @michau Thanks for addressing the concern - Updated the answer to include the `split`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have common pattern for input strings? If yes, then create a case class for it, use regexps to unapply into that case class, and `sortBy` some field.

Comment: No, ther're just strings and numbers separated by commas and dashes

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the beginning of each string follows the same pattern (Int-String-Int), I coded the following

```
 object StringIntSorter extends App {

 @throws(classOf[java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException])
 @throws(classOf[java.lang.NumberFormatException])
  def lt(a: String, b: String): Boolean = {
    def getKey(s: String): Tuple3[Int, String, Int] = {

      val a = s.split("-|,| ")
      (Integer.parseInt(a(0), 10), a(1), Integer.parseInt(a(2), 10))
    }

    math.Ordering[Tuple3[Int, String, Int]].lt(getKey(a), getKey(b))
  }

  val sampleData = List("0203-foo-02 bar", "0201-woo-21 bar foo 21 bar", "201-foo2-02", "200-foo3-01")
  val sorted = sampleData.sortWith(lt(_, _))

  println("Unsorted: " + sampleData.mkString("; "))
  println("Sorted:   " + sorted.mkString("; "))
}
```